# How to send a time stamp with a message to firebase database in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to store `Time Stamp` for every message a user sends to firebase database. Is this a right way to do ?

Somewhere in my code, I used the following.

```
Message message = new Message(null, mUserName, downloadUrl.toString(),ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
messagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(message);
```

I'm getting this error when I try to run my app.

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a Map while deserializing, but got a class java.lang.Long
```

This is my **Model** class, `Message`:

```
public class Message {

    private String text;
    private String name;
    private String photoUrl;
    private Map<String,String> timeStamp;

    public Map<String, String> getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(Map<String, String> timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public Message(String text, String name, String photoUrl, Map<String,String> timeStamp) {
        this.text = text;
        this.name = name;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

      // Other getters and setters 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've remodeled my **Model** class, `Message` to:

```
public class Message {

  private String text;
  private String name;
  private String photoUrl;
  private String dateAndTime;

  public Message(String text, String name, String photoUrl, String dateAndTime){
    this.text = text;
    this.name = name;
    this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    this.dateAndTime = dateAndTime;
  }
  // getters and setters
}
```

In the `MainActivity`, I have implemented the following for sending the Time Stamp along with a user's message to Firebase Database. It worked!

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd hh:mm a");
String dateAndTime = formatter.format(date);
Message message = new Message(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(), mUserName, null, dateAndTime);
messagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are getting the error message when you are retrieving the `timestamp` from the database. The rule is, that when you are setting the `timestamp` you setting it as a `Map` and when you are retrieving, you are retrieving as a `Long`. So in order to get it correct, i suggest you using this method:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return "date";
    }
}
```

If you want to retrieve only the date, please use the following method:

```
static String getDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return "date";
    }
}
```

When you are retrieving the `timestamp`, put a listener on the specific node and iterate over the map like this:

```
if (entry.getKey().equals("timeStamp")) {
    Long timeStampLong = (Long) entry.getValue();
    String timeStamp = getDate(timeStampLong);
    ((TextView )findViewById(R.id.time_stamp)).setText(timeStamp);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So should I keep this in my `Message` class ?

Comment: I would do that and will get back to you! Appreciate it.

Comment: Ok. Keep me posted.

Comment: Still I'm getting the same. 
`public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                    mMessageAdapter.add(message);
                }` The errors is pointing this line -- `Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);`

Comment: Can you please help!

Comment: Any of the above methods didn't work. I changed the field `Map<String, String> timeStamp` to `String timeStamp`. I created a new instance of `Date` formatted it using `SimpleDateFormat` and sent to Firebase storage. Thanks for the help and time!

Comment: Happy to hear that. If you think that my answer helped you in any way, consider accepting it and giving a +1. Thanks!